# Is event loop cleared in node js on error thrown?

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling

I am trying to execute the code which throws and error while code execution. I wanna know whether asynchronous call is cleared when error is thrown?

For example:

```
try{
  axios(api) // will asynchronous call continue to execute even though error is thrown?
  throw new Error();
}catch(e){

}
```

Comment: Have you tried this? It seems pretty easy to figure out.

Comment: Yes I have tried it, but event loop can't guarantee when will be call execution is completed. Hence not sure about it 

Comment: Yes, but if you set up an experiment where the asynchronous call did something trivial, like `console.log()`. and then ran your code above, you'd have your answer instantaneously.

Comment: Why would it be "cleared" (whatever that means exactly)? And what does the event loop have to do with it?

Comment: @Bergi cleared means, the asynchronous API call will get successfully executed when an error is thrown?

Comment: @AkshayBande The call happens before the error is thrown, so why wouldn't it execute successfully?

Comment: @Bergi yes you are correct for synchrounous execution, axios call is asynchronous call, it will get added to event loop and compiler will immediately execute the next statement. I wanna know whether event loop execution is affected when error is thrown?

Comment: @AkshayBande No, I think you misunderstand what an asynchronous call is. The `axios()` call will run all the statements inside the `axios` function, some of which will spawn a background task. Then it throws (and catches) the error. Then when the background task is done, it puts an event and a callback function in the event loop queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `axios()` call will run all the statements inside the `axios` function, some of which will spawn a background job. Then it throws (and catches) the error. Then when the background job is done, it puts an event and a callback function in the event loop queue.

The exception (especially if caught) will not clear any running background jobs, it doesn't have any knowledge about them, and it would be pretty confusing action at a distance to have your background jobs cancelled only if an exception happens elsewhere in the application.

The only way for this to happen is when the exception is not caught, in which case node.js crashes the entire process, stops the event loop and kills any background jobs.